# Error converting nvarchar to int in ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: asp.net

I am getting an error for the following program in asp.net.
I have checked sql and name is in nvarchar.

```
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("bookinsertion2", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnumber",txtid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", txtyear.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", txtdepart.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookname", ddlbookavail.SelectedItem.ToString());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("~/LendingForm2.aspx");
}
```

This is the code of the stored procedure

```
create Procedure [dbo].[bookinsertion2]
@idnumber int,
@name nvarchar(20),
@year int,  
@department nvarchar(30),
@bookname nvarchar(25)
as
Begin
   insert into tbllendinginfo values(@idnumber,@name,@year,@department,@bookname)
   insert into tbllendinginfo(Dateofbooktaken) values(GETDATE())
   update tblbookinfo set BooksAvailable=BooksAvailable-(select COUNT(Id) from tbllendinginfo where BookName=@bookname) where Name=@bookname
end
```

The error is " Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Mike' to data type int. "

Comment: Are you sure that ALL parameters expected by the stored procedure are of type nvarchar? (@year for example)

Comment: I'd also be suspect of idnumber and potentially department (is that a department id?) as well...

Comment: Post the stored procedure 'bookinsertion2'.

Comment: i am new to asp.net and sql. can you please tell me what is ALL parameters

Comment: Open the stored procedure using SQL Server Management Studio or the Server Explorer window of Visual Studio. You should see the declaration of the stored procedure and the list of parameters expected. Could you post them here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear, one or more of the parameters expected by the stored procedure are not of type nvarchar. Probably the @year and @idnumber parameters are an integers. If that's true then you need to call

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnumber",Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", Convert.ToInt32(txtyear.Text));
```

Said that, please try, if possible to avoid the call to AddWithValue, in particular in case where strings or date are involved. AddWithValue determines the type of the parameter from the input value and most of the time is correct, but there are situations where it decides for a wrong datatype and the errors are difficult to find. Moreover AddWithValue with strings is a performance hurdle.
A better explanation could be found in these two articles.

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
[How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

You could rewrite the code above using the Object Initializer Syntax

```
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("bookinsertion2", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add( 
         new SqlParameter
         { 
             ParameterName = "@idnumber", 
             SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, 
             Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text)
         });
    cmd.Parameters.Add( 
         new SqlParameter
         { 
             ParameterName = "@name", 
             SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
             Size = 50,
             Value = txtname.Text
         });
    cmd.Parameters.Add( 
         new SqlParameter
         { 
             ParameterName = "@year", 
             SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, 
             Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtyear.Text)
         });
    cmd.Parameters.Add( 
         new SqlParameter
         { 
             ParameterName = "@department", 
             SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
             Size = 50,
             Value = txtdepart.Text
         });
    cmd.Parameters.Add( 
         new SqlParameter
         { 
             ParameterName = "@bookname", 
             SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
             Size = 50,
             Value = ddlbookavail.SelectedItem.ToString()
         });

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("~/LendingForm2.aspx");
}
```

**EDIT**
After your edit I think the problem is in this line of the stored procedure:

```
insert into tbllendinginfo values(@idnumber,@name,@year,@department,@bookname)
```

You haven't specified the columns' names but just the parameters. So the server inserts the parameter following the order of definition of the columns in the datatable.
Of course, if the second column in the table is not the column that should receive the @name parameter you could have serious problems.

You could fix the problem listing the name of the columns in the same order iun which you put the parameter inside the VALUES clause or changing the order of the parameters to follow the order of the column names.

For example (I don't know the column names so you should fix them)

```
insert into tbllendinginfo (idnumber, name, bookyear, department, bookname) 
                           values(@idnumber,@name,@year,@department,@bookname)
```

Comment: Could you open the StoredProcedure text and post the first lines to your question above?

Comment: @idnumber int,@name nvarchar(50),@year int,@department nvarchar(50),@bookname nvarchar(50)

Comment: OK so `@idnumber` and `@year` need to be passed as integers. Adding the conversion to the two textboxes content should remove the error.

Comment: now its showing error as input string was not in correct format at sqlparameter for @name

Comment: Change the Size to 50 and make the other parameters of the same size defined in the nvarchar(xx) declaration

Comment: I think that if we want to solve your problem you should post the code of the Stored Procedure. Please do it in your question, not in comments here below. Just press the Edit link button and add this stored procedure code. And don't forget the exact error message received now